# Search AD for users that are memberof multiple groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get all users that have local admin rights to their work stations, this is specified under the memberof property, i also need to filter by another group under the memberof property. I have created something similar

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN, StreetAddress, memberof |
Where-Object 
{$_.memberof.contains('RemovalStorage-R') -and 
 $_.memberof.contains('EU-IRL-Dublin' )
 } | 
Select DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN | Sort-Object Displayname
```

Now i need to change the first group to something like

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN, StreetAddress, memberof |
Where-Object 
{$_.memberof.contains('EU-EIE*-LocalAdmins') -and 
 $_.memberof.contains('EU-IRL-Dublin' )
 } | 
Select DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN | Sort-Object Displayname
```

the EIE* is the beginning of the workstation name so need to be able to search a wildcard to get the rest of the name:
EIE123,
EIE124,
EIE125,
EIE126

Thanks in advance for any response.
Kind rgds,
Dan

Comment: Use double quotes and change it to like `$_.memberof -like ("EU-EIE*-LocalAdmins")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes mean to take the string literally, and contains is similar to -eq, where it has to match exactly, providing a True or False Answer. So right now you're saying search for something that is EXACTLY EU-EIE*-LocalAdmins. If you swap the quotes to double quotes and change .Contains to -like, you'll have better luck.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN, StreetAddress, memberof |
Where-Object 
{$_.memberof -like ("EU-EIE*-LocalAdmins") -and 
$_.memberof.contains('EU-IRL-Dublin' )
} | 
Select DisplayName, EmailAddress, CN | Sort-Object Displayname
```

Just a note, your environment may be different than mine, but running your line gives the DN of their member of, meaning you get the OU=X DC= X, so you may want both to use Like, and put a wildcard on each end.

```
-like "*Word*One*"
```